# Change powershell script so that it checks ping

Tags: powershell

Can someone please modify the script below so that IP changes stop not when IP starts with a certain value, instead, when ping to some host (say ya.ru) is less than, for example, 80 ms?

```
 [string]$ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
while(!$ip.StartsWith('95.56')){
    ipconfig /release
    ipconfig /renew
    $ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your script is questionable and I highly doubt the admin of the DHCP server would approve.  I would also expect you to need a `start-sleep` after obtaining the ip address before trying to use it but I'm not going to run it to find out.

However you can IP from PowerShell like this:

```
$ping = new-object System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping
$result = ping.send("8.8.8.8")
Write-Host $result.RoundtripTime
```